# Can you link a movieclip to a point on an externally loaded image in Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, zooming, movieclip, pan

[EDIT]
Please see the code.
I can load the image, I can load the movie clip. The image zooms and pans to user input. But the movieclip (mcInfo) needs to be "attached" to a point on the image to insure it zooms and pans with the image.
The reason for this is because the image is a large scale irrigation installation which consists of a lot of different products. The information icon (mcInfo) should be a click-able movieclip to display the information of that product.
There is going to be a lot of those icons on the image. But it has to correlate to the product that the user wants to view.

```
var spImage:Sprite = new Sprite(); //load image to sprite "I think"
board.addChild(spImage);    

function initPic(e:Event):void {
      infoBox.text = "";
      infoBox.visible = false;
      image = Bitmap(loader.content);
      minScale = boardWidth/image.width;
      image.scaleX = minScale;
      image.scaleY = minScale;

      spImage.addChild(image);// the loaded image
      spImage.addChild(mcIn); // custom zoom in cursor
      spImage.addChild(mcOut); // custom zoom out cursor
      spImage.addChild(mcInfo); //information icon. This is the movieclip that I need to set at a point 

      spImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging);
      stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);

      loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, initPic);
      loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, updateInfo);
      loader = null;

      board.filters = [ new DropShadowFilter() ];
      spImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, zoom);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your loaded image inside a `Sprite`, then add the desired `DescriptionObject` whereever you want inside the same `Sprite`. From now on do all the zooming and panning on the `Sprite` instead of the loaded image.
Your image becomes fully available when `Event.COMPLETE` event of the `loaded.contentLoaderInfo` triggers. Inside `initPic` function do:

```
theSprite.addChild(event.target.content) //adds your image to the Sprite object
theSprite.addChild(description); 
description.x = 100;
description.y = 200;
```

Comment: var spImage:Sprite = new Sprite();
    board.addChild(spImage);

Comment: Please see the revised question

Comment: Could you make a question statement with ? at the end?:)
I don't exactly understand what is your question.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow link movieclips to certain points on a image for zooming and panning?

Comment: Add movieclips at certain points in the same container object where the image is added and zoom,pan the container. Or you can calculate positions of movieclips on every frame.